# Spotify Android SDK Authentication Service unknown

Tags: android, authentication, spotify

I'm building an app that utilizes the Spotify Android SDK.
Up until now, this code (that I got from the official Spotify tutorials) always worked flawlessly to authenticate a user and obtain an access token:

```
AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID,
                        AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN,
                        REDIRECT_URI);
                builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming"});
                AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

                AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);
```

and

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if result comes from the correct activity
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);

        switch (response.getType()) {
            // Response was successful and contains auth token
            case TOKEN:
                // Handle successful response
                accessToken = response.getAccessToken();
                Config playerConfig = new Config(this, response.getAccessToken(), CLIENT_ID);
                Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer spotifyPlayer) {
                        mPlayer = spotifyPlayer;
                        mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(MainActivity.this);
                        mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(MainActivity.this);
                        Log.d("Player", "has been set");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                break;

            // Auth flow returned an error
            case ERROR:
                Log.d("Error message", response.getError());
                Log.d("Error", response.toString());
                // Handle error response
                break;

            // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
            default:
                // Handle other cases
        }
    }
}
```

However, this has stopped working and I get the following error:

D/com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication.LoginActivity: Error authenticating

the log returns:

D/Error message: AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNKNOWN_ERROR

And the received responseCode is -1.
I am pretty clueless as to how my method is wrong and as such tend to assume that somehow Spotify's authentication backend has some hiccups.

For now I am stuck using the browser login, which is fine I guess, but LoginActivity login would definitely be nicer. Does someone know what may cause the error?